# How can I make citations of expression used in my own text using superscript?

Tags: beamer, titles

I am writing a presentation, and in title page I have the authors names, and I want to  reference those names to the email, which I'll write bellow. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %codificação de caracteres ã é etc
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\mode<presentation> {
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}



\title[short title]{long title} % The short title appears at the bottom ofevery slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Author 1\\ \and Author 2} % Your name
\institute[U] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of everslide, may be shorthand to save space
{
\textbf{F} \\ DM % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

%email 1
%email2
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example we can copy-paste-compile. This should include the document class, the `document` environment and sufficient content to demonstrate the problem or situation.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for adding the relevant tags! I would have never seen it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are packages exactly for this purpose, but some of them do not play nicly with beamer. For my own theme I therefore just use this simple command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}

\newcommand{\insta}[1]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}$^{#1}$}}

\title[short title]{long title}
\author[Author 1 \and Author 2]{Author 1\insta{1} \and Author 2\insta{2}} 
\institute[U]{\insta{1}\href{mailto:user@example.com}{user@example.com} \quad \insta{2}\href{mailto:user@example.com}{user@example.com}}
\date{\today} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]